# How to refresh only specific component after anything on the page is click/changed in angualarJS

Tags: angularjs

i have my appilcation which shows number of active session which iam getting from stroage

```
<a>Active Sessions(this.countOfSessions)<a>
```

After clicking on active session it will display actual sessions

```
_getActiveSession(){
this.getSessions().then(
result =>{
this.sessions=res;
this.countOfSessions = res.Count;
}
);
}
```

But in my page the count is not getting refreshed until i hard refresh the page, but the result has all the active session but count value is showing older value

correct number of sessions to be shown